# Week average pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following data on excel:

```
day | week | #pieces

1 | 1 | 5

2 | 1 | 5

3 | 1 | 5

4 | 1 | 5

5 | 1 | 5

1 | 2 | 5

2 | 2 | 5

3 | 2 | 5

4 | 2 | 5

5 | 2 | 5

1 | 3 | 5

2 | 3 | 5
```

I did a pivot table that gets the total of #pieces per week.

Now I want to get the average of #pieces per week. I tried to use a calculated field using #pieces/5 but this is not always true for the current week. See week 3 for example:

```
Week | Average #pieces

1 | 5

2 | 5

3 | 2 (this number '2' should be also '5')
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand what you're trying to do, you don't need a calculated field (which is messing you up, by the way, because you're dividing by the hard-coded 5).

I would pivot with `week number` as your row label and `average of pieces` as your values. You can change sum to average in the value field options of the pivot table.

Comment: nickflees, i could use average function if i dont have more than one entry to the same day. Example:

day | week | #pieces | category

1 | 1 | 5 | A

1 | 1 | 5 | B

is there some way to average function of distinct values?

Comment: @IgorGois can you clarify what you mean? I'm not talking about using the `AVERAGE` function, but rather changing the Value Field Settings in the pivot table to show the average and not the sum (or count), depending on the default behavior.

Comment: i understood what you mean. But in this case, the average in value field setting doesnt work because i have a column named 'category'. Thus I use more than one row to the same day:

day | week | #pieces | category

1 | 1 | 5 | A

1 | 1 | 5 | B

2 | 1 | 5 | A

2 | 1 | 5 | B

3 | 1 | 5 | A

3 | 1 | 5 | B

4 | 1 | 5 | A

4 | 1 | 5 | B

5 | 1 | 5 | A

5 | 1 | 5 | B

In this case, the #pieces average returns 50/10 = 5 pieces per day in week 1. But what I need is the result 50/5 (5 days in this week) = 10 pieces per day in week 1.

Please do not hesitate if you didnt understand.

Comment: What is the role of the `category` column? Do you want category averages as well? If so, the pivot table solution can be modified. It's not totally clear now what you're asking for.